# Как в симуляторе vax 11 провести анализ младшего бита числа?

Tags: математика

Делаю умножение целых чисел со знаком в дополнительном коде с  неподвижной суммой частичных произведений, сдвигом множимого влево и анализом множителя,  начиная с младших разрядов.
Можно не именно на vax, а на ассемблере или еще где.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще где (C)

```
int r1;
if (r1 & 1) {
    // bit is set
}
```

На PDP-11 точно не помню, что то вроде

```
and  r1,#1  ; абсолютно забыл, какой порядок операндов и как задать непосредственный
bnz  bitset ; переход, если r1 после операции не 0
```

Cмутно вспоминая систему команд VAX, д.б. команда тестирования по маске, не разрушающая операнд.

А у Вас таблица команд под рукой ?

Comment: Спасибо, Это то что надо. Да, таблица есть. Переход задать не проблема.